# Build context isn't defined for the class

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a show dialog function in a separate file and calling it into another file, feeding the functions 4 parameters including the BuildContext parameter as shown

```
void showDialogSingleButton(BuildContext context, String title, String 
message, String buttonLabel) {


showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
  return AlertDialog(
    title:
    new Text(title),
    content:
    new Text(message),
    actions: <Widget>[
      new FlatButton(
        child:
        new Text(buttonLabel),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.
          of(context).pop();
        },
      ),
    ],
   );
  },
 );
}
```

And calling it in this file a future object as a show dialog function:

```
Future launchURL(String url) async {

if(await canLaunch(url)) {

  await launch(url, forceSafariVC: true, forceWebView: true);
}
else {
  showDialogSingleButton( context, "Unable to reach your website.", 
"Currently unable to reach the website $URL. Please try again at a later 
time.", "OK");
 }
}
```

And it's giving me this error for some reason when i call the method:

```
  Compiler message:
  lib/screens/login/login_page.dart:45:31: Error: Getter not found: 
  'context'.
  showDialogSingleButton( context, "Unable to reach your website.", 
  "Currently unable to reach the website $URL. Please try again at a 
  later 
  time.", "OK");
                          ^^^^^^^
  lib/screens/login/login_page.dart:45:31: Error: The getter 'context' 
  isn't defined for the class 'LoginScreen'.
  - 'LoginScreen' is from 
  'package:gam3ity_aa/screens/login/login_page.dart' 
  ('lib/screens/login/login_page.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining 
   a getter or field named 'context'.
  showDialogSingleButton( context, "Unable to reach your website.", 
  "Currently unable to reach the website $URL. Please try again at a 
  later 
  time.", "OK");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `launchUrl` function `context` may not exist, hard to tell without seeing more of your code.

A great way to continue to debug is to add BuildContext as a parameter to the function `launchUrl`. You should do this anyways, `launchUrl` should not be referencing class level variables just better, more maintainable code to be explicit about every variable that a function needs to reference.

```
Future launchURL(String url) async {

if(await canLaunch(url)) {

  await launch(url, forceSafariVC: true, forceWebView: true);
}
else {
  //HERE, DOES CONTEXT EXIST??
  showDialogSingleButton( context, "Unable to reach your website.", 
"Currently unable to reach the website $URL. Please try again at a later 
time.", "OK");
 }
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't cuz i already declared it in the original function

Comment: Thanks, just solved it, added the context as a variable like you said